# Is an autorelease pool necessary if I'm not creating autoreleased objects?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, nsautoreleasepool

I mean, if I were absolutely certain I wasn't creating any autoreleased objects, then of course it wouldn't. My real concern is if there's anything else under the hood I don't understand. I have a background thread that calls a function. Must I always create an autorelease pool anyway?

```
- (void)someFuncOnABackgroundThread
{
    //don't seem to need this. no leaks found
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    //do something that doesn't create any objects, or only use alloc/init/release

    NSString* str = [[NSString alloc] init];
    [str release];
    [pool drain];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ultimately, it depends on the interfaces you're using in the implementation.

**example 1**

if you're interacting with Foundation or other objc types, you should. without question.

to answer specific to the example you've posted: definitely create one in this case -- NSString apis should assume an autorelease pool is in place.

**example 2**

if you're dealing entirely with apis in libc, there is no need.

**bottom line**

- it can take a lot of time to understand where it's necessary (or not).
- implementations can change, and they could introduce autoreleased objects.
- you should guarantee a leak is never introduced, especially for such a simple reason.
- it's a simple problem to overcome: if in doubt, create one.

Answer (score 2):

Yep! You have to. You might be calling a function that's internally using autorelease pools, so you never really know if you're using or not any autorelease.

Good luck!

Comment: Some clarification: if your function is on the main thread and you're using UIKit (which, of course, you are) then no, you don't need to create your own pool; one is created at the beginning of every event loop and drained at the end. If you're making calls outside of the main thread **and** you're making Cocoa Touch calls of any kind (like your NSString), you do need to create one. Both must be true, however, to need one.